# Simplify expression with lambert w-Function

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

I have an expression and i am almost sure what it equals:

$
e^{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{log\left(x\right)}{x}\right)}
$

I only need a simplified version of this expression for $x\geq e$.

I assume:

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}: \left(x\geq e\right)\Rightarrow \left(e^{-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{log\left(x\right)}{x}\right)}=x\right)$

I tested it with some values, but i did not find a general way to prove this. Maybe someone has an idea?

Thank you,

Regards
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X=-\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$

and  $y=e^{-W(X)}$  hense  $W(X)=-\ln(y)$

By definition of the $W$ function :  $W(X) e^{W(X)}=X$

$-\ln(y) e^{-\ln(y)}=X$

$-\frac{\ln(y)}{y}=X=-\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$

$y=x$

$x=y=e^{-W(X)}= e^{-W\left(-\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right)}$